# Past perfect and perfect continuous: a difference in meaning?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, tenses, past-perfect

> - The pavement was wet, it had been raining.
> - The pavement was wet, it had rained.

What's the difference?

Comment: `The pavement was wet, it had been raining.` or `The pavement was wet, it had been raining.` As far as I can see, there's literally no difference.

Comment: My fault. But i have corrected it.....

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference and an error.

"The pavement was wet, it had been raining." - There're two independent clauses, which cannot be connected to make one single sentence unless a *conjunction* is used. Otherwise, a semi-colon should be used to separate them.

Let's rewrite the same with *as*:

The pavement was wet *as* it had been raining. - Here, what's implied is the fact that it rained earlier *and it rained for quite some time*. Readers get that impression, although implicit, due to the use of *past perfect continuous* tense.

The other example, "The pavement was wet, it had rained." also needs either a conjunction, viz., *as* or a semi-colon. Here, you're simply putting the focus on the *the fact that it rained earlier* with no reference or implication of time, and hence the use of *past perfect* tense.